# Admob Banners without gambling or 'sexy' content

Tags: admob, banner, ads

I want to prevent gambling or 'sexy' content in Admob banners. Are the following my only two options?

Google Admob allows for a content setting for children:
Set tagForChildDirectedTreatment to YES to indicates that you want your content treated as child-directed for purposes of COPPA.

Admob also has this keyword targeting setting:
request.contentURL = @"http://websiteWithoutAnyHintOfGambling.com";

From:https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/ios/targeting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can limit ad categories on [AdMob](https://www.google.com/admob/).

To get to the [Sensitive Categories](https://apps.admob.com/?pli=1#monetize/pubcontrols:sensitive-categories) section, navigate through Monetize>All Apps>Sensitive Categories.

There are many different categories you can enable and disable including Gambling, and References to Sex and Sexuality.

[image]

You can also do this on an app for app basis by selecting Monetize>[Your App]>Allow & Block Ads

Comment: Thanks Daniel, that's it. The two options I mentioned can be set in the code for runtime adjustments. Obviously there are also the general campaign settings, hadn't seen them yet.

Comment: @RobvandenBerg I'd recommend disabling "Dating" also. I found the ads to be a little risqué a few years ago. I doubt they've changed much since then.